# #each works on ul/li but not on tbody/tr

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following data that I am rendering twice in the same HTML file.

```
{ clients: [
    {_id:1234,'Client Name':'Mr Ed Voice Coaching','POC Name':'Mr Ed','POC Email':'Horse@Mr.Ed','POC TelNo':12345678},
    {_id:1234,'Client Name':'Mr Ed Voice Coaching','POC Name':'Mr Ed','POC Email':'Horse@Mr.Ed','POC TelNo':12345678}
]}
```

It works fine when rendered as LIs and SPANs within a UL.

```
  <ul>
    {{#each clients}}
    <li>
      <span>{{_id}}, </span>
      <span>{{'Client Name'}}, </span>
      <span>{{'POC Name'}}, </span>
      <span>{{'POC Email'}}, </span>
      <span>{{'POC TelNo'}}</span>
    </li>
    {{/each}}   </ul>
```

However, it fails to render when used within a TBODY as TRs containing TDs.

```
  <table><tbody>
    {{#each clients}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{_id}}</td>
      <td>{{'Client Name'}}</td>
      <td>{{'POC Name'}}</td>
      <td>{{'POC Email'}}</td>
      <td>{{'POC TelNo'}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody></table>
```

I cannot find a problem when tested in http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Have you tried using only `{{#clients}} ... {{/clients}}` instead? What does *fails to render* mean? Did you inspect your table and nothing was inside `<tbody>` or was it some compilation case?

Comment: Thank you @wscourge for your input, it sounded encouraging but did not work. I got a similar output to before. Which is; I get a TR with empty TDs and the `{{#clients}} {{/clients}}` in injected as text above the table for some reason. I am setting the `innerHTML` property of the TBODY rather than using an `appendChild` method but this is only a sampler not production code.